# Sending messages to specific threads/users in instant messaging app

Tags: java

I'm currently writing an IM server in Java for a web-based chat application using the new WebSocket protocol.  The server currently listens for connections and creates a new thread for each connecting client that handles input and output.  However, I cannot figure out how I'd go about sending messages between specific threads.

I've set it to where the web-based client sends the users ID to the server and that ID is used as the thread name using `currentThread.setName()` but I'm not sure where to go from there.

I'm only about 3 weeks into Java so the answer to my question may be ridiculously simple or I may be going about this whole thing completely wrong.  I just need a push in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should re-invent the wheel, try using [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) for chat implementation

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll check out JGroups, but this is a project I'm doing more so for learning purposes than anything so I'd rather not rely on anyone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of messages do you want to send?  One thing that you could try is storing your Threads in a List that all your Threads can access, searching for the Thread that you want to send the message to, then calling a method on the thread:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
  private static List<MyThread> chatClients;

  public void run(){
    for (MyThread t : chatClients){
      if (...){
        t.sendMessage(...);
      }
    }
    //...
  }

  public void sendMessage(...){
    //...
  }
}
```

Also note that, because you are dealing with threads, you must keep synchronization in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The messages will just be strings. Your solution would definitely work.  But, and I may just be being paranoid, would looping through a list be the most efficient way to select a thread to pass data to?

Comment: No you are not being paranoid, you are being smart. :) Depending on your situation, there's probably a better way to do it.  I just wanted to throw an example together.

Comment: Use a Map and key off the User/Client you want to send the message to.